# Does an electrical outlet radiate EM waves?

Tags: antenna, radiation, outlet

Please consider all cases **even** with a tiny values.

If plug two separated wires to each terminal of electrical outlet, like shown, will it radiate em waves?

[image]

`60 hz, 230 V electrical outlet.`

Wires are not connected to each other(I mean in our ends, cause, somewhere in generator they should be connected)

If it will radiate, then  will radiate both wires or only that connected to phase terminal(seems it called "hot" terminal in eng)?

Comment: What do the two separated wires add compared to the wires leading to the socket?

Comment: @Jeroen3, didn't understand the question. What is the difference between conneted and unconnected wires, or what?

Answer (score 9):

Adding the wires is a bit pointless as there are already wires (in the wall) leading to the socket, and they also radiate EM waves just like the wires added by you.

So that answers your question: yes EM waves are radiated. **But** since the mains power is at a **very low frequency** effective radiation of the EM waves would require an antenna that is about 1500 kilometers long (that's for a \$\lambda/4\$ antenna). The wires in our house are **much shorter** and therefor do not radiate very well at 60 Hz.

So yes, EM waves are indeed radiated but they're extremely weak and that's good as we want to electrical power to be used for something useful and not be radiated into space.

Comment: First, You are wrong when said, that it will not radiated to space. Higher wavelength - higher penetration, i.e. 50 hz wave can pass through 6 000 000 meters obstacle.

Comment: You write, adding wires is pointless, and next write that wave depends on wire length. Cool..

Comment: And the same question - "effective radiation" " weak radiation", it is very blurry. What do You mean by this terms? Low energy? Low intensity?

Comment: @Arthur: You seem to take a strange attitude to those who try to help you. Bimpelrekkie did not say that power frequency waves will not be radiated into space. S/he is saying that the fact that the radiated energy is so weak is a good thing because "we  want to electrical power to be used for something useful **rather than** be radiated into space". I suggest that you try to understand what is being written, take the author's reputation as some measure of expertise and knowledge and modify your tone in the comments. If you're not getting a satisfactory answer then improve your question.

Comment: @Artur If you know it all so well then why are you asking a question? That means not nitpicking on the exact wording of the answer but trying to understand the **line of thought**. Your commenting only shows your lack of understanding and that's fine, we were all born not understanding this. Your attitude however leaves a lot to be desired so I'm not answering your questions anymore. And a -1 for your question of course.

Comment: The **electric** field can be a problem, with the displacement current. 1 meter of wire, 1mm diameter, placed 1mm from a sensitive circuit, has capacitance of about 10picoFarads. At 60Hz and 160volts peak, or 50,000 volts/second slewrate, the induced current from (Q = C*V) I = C * dV/dT = 10pF * 50,000 = 500,000pA or 0.5 microAmps. Can your circuit provide a high SignalNoiseRatio, with 0.5 microAmps at 60Hz as an interfering tone?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it will radiate a 60Hz  (or 50Hz depending on where you live) wave.  It will be weak.  **Very** weak.  So weak that there's no point in worrying about it.

The radiated power depends the wavelength of the wave and the length of the two wires.  To do any good, you'd want each wire to be about 1/4 of the wavelength.

For 60Hz, the wavelength is close to 5000km.  At 50Hz, that'd be nearly 6000km.  So, you'd need wires of 1250 or 1500km to transmit a large amount of power.

As you can see, the wire length needed to "transmit" at the AC powerline frequency is quite long.

No wire you can practically connect inside of your house can transmit an appreciable amount of power.

The "transmitted" power will appear to come from both wires if your receiver is not grounded.

If the receiver is grounded the the power will appear to come from the "hot" wire of the socket.

---

Even considering the length of the wires in the house (as Jeroen3 suggests) doesn't get you any notable amount of power.

You can measure it if you try.  Engineers and technicians do it accidentally all the time - then curse, and improve the shielding and grounding on the extremely sensitive circuits and measuring devices they are using.

An oscilloscope, a loop of wire, and a capacitor can be made into a device to detect the AC being "broadcast" around.  This only works because modern equipment is extraordinarily sensitive.  If you assemble such a device, you can calculate how much power is being intentionally received - and the (miniscule) total will surprise you.  Something on the order of millionths of a watt.

Comment: First, You didn't answer to complete question(which wire will radiate - both or hot). The second, Your statement that the em wave frequency will be 60 hz is absolutely false(it's my opinion, at least). Third, what does "weak" mean? It's blurry a lot. If You meant intensity, it doesn't depends on frequency

Comment: AC power like from an outlet is either 60Hz (USA) or 50Hz (most of the rest of the world.)  Anything broadcast **will** be at the frequency of the power line - ignoring any garbage put on it by noisy appliances.

Comment: Intensity depends on the available power, and the antenna.  The size of antenna needed depends on the frequency - which is why I referred to the line frequency in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is a blurry answer.  You have blurry specifications on what is in effect a question about concepts.  A specific answer is not possible, and not really useful.

Comment: Interesting that you complain about my answer being "blurry" when it in fact contains more numbers and order of magnitude references than the other answer.

Comment: cheer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/401477/201246

Comment: @Artur you are quite confused.  You simply don't get frequency components without physical mechanisms which can generate them.  Typically those are non-linearities, which are not present here but even if present only produce harmonically related ones.   Non harmonically related components would have to come from a distinct mechanism, ie another oscillator, thermal emission, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton what do You mean by frequency components?

Comment: @Artur rather than posing a continuing series of weird questions which are too divergent and uninformed by foundation concepts to lead to actual understanding, perhaps try learning about this subject from traditional materials.  There's a wealth of knowledge out there online.